# Send me an email on computer shutdown

Tags: scripts, shutdown, email

I would like the computer to send me an email everytime it starts or it shuts down. I found [this code written for CENTOS](https://linuxaria.com/pills/email-on-shutdown-and-restart-linux) and am trying to adapt it to Ubuntu.

The code is:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# chkconfig: 2345 99 01
# Description: Sends an email at system start and shutdown

#############################################
#                                           #
# Send an email on system start/stop to     #
# a user.                                   #
#                                           #
#############################################

EMAIL="email@email.com"
RESTARTSUBJECT="["`hostname`"] - System Startup"
SHUTDOWNSUBJECT="["`hostname`"] - System Shutdown"
RESTARTBODY="This is an automated message to notify you that "`hostname`" started successfully.

Start up Date and Time: "`date`
SHUTDOWNBODY="This is an automated message to notify you that "`hostname`" is shutting down.
Shutdown Date and Time: "`date`
LOCKFILE=/var/lock/subsys/SystemEmail
RETVAL=0

# Source function library.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

stop()
{
echo -n $"Sending Shutdown Email: "
echo "${SHUTDOWNBODY}" | mail -s "${SHUTDOWNSUBJECT}" ${EMAIL}
RETVAL=$?

if [ ${RETVAL} -eq 0 ]; then
rm -f ${LOCKFILE}
success
else
failure
fi
echo
return ${RETVAL}
}

start()
{
echo -n $"Sending Startup Email: "
echo "${RESTARTBODY}" | mail -s "${RESTARTSUBJECT}" ${EMAIL}
RETVAL=$?

if [ ${RETVAL} -eq 0 ]; then
touch ${LOCKFILE}
success
else
failure
fi
echo
return ${RETVAL}
}

case $1 in
stop)
stop
;;

start)
start
;;

*)

esac
exit ${RETVAL}
```

Where the `/lib/lsb/init-functions` is different from the original code to be compatible with Ubuntu.

The error I'm getting trying to run this is (the name of the file is `mailme`)

```
Unit mailme.service failed to load: No such file or directory
```

What can I do for this code to run on Ubuntu? Are the modifications large?

Comment: This is the old System V way of using system scripts. This was replaced by Upstart, which in its turn was replaced by `systemd`. The term "Unit mailme.service" is a giveaway that you are on a systemd version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your error message, it seems you're running a version of Ubuntu that uses systemd. I think it would be easier if you separated out the mail-sending part into a separate script and execute it using a systemd service.

So, taking out the mailing part (and simplifying it):

```sh
#! /bin/sh
EMAIL="email@email.com"
SUBJECT="[$HOSTNAME] - System $1"

if [ "$1" = startup ]
then
    ACTION="started successfully"
else
    ACTION="is shutting down"
fi

# a printf format string to simplify a long body
BODY="This is an automated message to notify you that %s %s.\nDate and Time: %s\n"

printf "$BODY" "$HOSTNAME" "$ACTION" "$(date)" | mail -s "${SUBJECT}" "${EMAIL}"
```

Save this as, say, `/usr/local/bin/bootmail.sh`, make it executable, etc.

Then, to create a systemd service, create a file in `/etc/systemd/system` with extension `.service` (for example, `/etc/systemd/system/bootmail.service`) containing:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run Scripts at Start and Stop

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/bootmail.sh startup
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/bootmail.sh shutdown

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now, do:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable bootmail.service
```

Now, you should get mails on startup and shutdown (assuming mailing is configured correctly, etc.).